# How to drag tab up and show toolbar in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a toolbar image which has a tab on top of it as part of the image. With the toolbar initially hidden except for the tab sticking up on the bottom of the screen, I would like the user to be able to press and drag up the tab which would drag up the rest of the toolbar with it. Likewise, I would like to be able to drag the toolbar back down by doing the reverse direction on the tab part of the toolbar.

What's a good way to implement that kind of functionality in iOS?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used UIScrollView to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a 'clear' button over the tab image and add an action handler for the 'touch up inside' or 'touch drag inside' events that runs a core animation to slide the toolbar up/down.

Alternately you can use touchesBegan/touchesEnded events in the view to do more fine grained control of the type of touch actions that should trigger the toolbar to slide up.  (i.e. for touch-drag up/down).